# How to change and disable other column same of record by changing numberfield widget

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid with three numberfield widgetcolumn.  Whenever I am changing the column A, I want column B and column C get change and and disable based on some backend response.

I have a couple of doubt here,

how to change the number and disable  of column B and Column C because `onchange`  is not disableing. So I am using `onwidgetAttach` which is firing on 
on change. But here the problem is suppose if there is 1000 records, it is getting fier by 1000 times. AlsoIf i remove any record it is not working correctly.

Here si my code.

```
onWidgetAttachColumnB : function(column, widget){

      _this.getCommonService().fetchDetails(options).then({
                    success: function (response){
                        widget.setValue(response.value);
                        widget.setDisabled(response.disable);                                    
                    }
        })
}





onWidgetAttachColumnC : function(column, widget){

      _this.getCommonService().fetchDetails(options).then({
                    success: function (response){
                        widget.setValue(response.value);
                        widget.setDisabled(response.disable);                                    
                    }
        })
}
```

Any work around.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that, each of them has advantages and disadvantages. To change column B and C depend on values of column A you can use calculated model fields:

```
Ext.define('TheModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'fieldA',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'fieldB',
        calculate: function (data) {
            return Math.pow(data.fieldA, 2);
        }
    }, {
        name: 'fieldC',
        calculate: function (data) {
            return Math.pow(data.fieldA, 3);
        }
    }, ]
});
```

To disabled columns depend on "some backend response" you can put in the model "invisible" filed which will not be listed in the grid column model and will come from backend and use this field value to disabled/enable columns.
In the followin fiddle sample I disabled the column from renderer function: [fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36pk)